# Hot to resolve Redirection Issue in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am developing one of website on magento platform and that website is on one of my demo server like 14.15.25.126/xyz but when i have shifted my code on main domain(www.xyz.com) from demo link and try to open my main website in browser then it is redirecting on my demo server 14.15.25.126/xyz. so please tell me what should i do for resolve thus issue.

Best Regards
Deepak

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration inside magento which forces this redirect . just go to the admin panel and select the system tab and the select configuration. The go the we b tab and change the base urls .

Answer (score 0):

This may be permission Issue, You need to give the proper permission "0777" to var, media and etc folder and please check the other file permission in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities are there

1. In core_config_data table, Locate the rows web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url and change the value.
2. Please check your .htaccess file for any redirections.